# Branches including only some directories

Tags: git

I work in a large and multi-user git repository. To avoid large checkouts I use sparse checkout which works well for me.

```
  ----------------- master -----------------------------------
  |                    |                    |   
ProjectA          ProjectB              ProjectC
```

Now I would like to create different branches, but I can't figure out the way of creating a branch which includes only one directory. Say I want to create a new branch which it will only includes `ProjectA`, can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make branches in normal way (suppose remote name is `origin`).

**Step 1**

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b ProjectA
git push -u origin ProjectA

git checkout master
git checkout -b ProjectB
git push -u origin ProjectB

git checkout master
git checkout -b ProjectC
git push -u origin ProjectC
```

**Step 2**

```
git checkout ProjectA
```

delete all directory not belong to ProjectA

```
git add -A .
git commit -m"All source code of ProjectA"
git push -u origin ProjectA
```

**Step 3**

```
git checkout ProjectB
```

delete all directory not belong to ProjectB

```
git add -A .
git commit -m"All source code of ProjectB"
git push -u origin ProjectB
```

**Step 4**

```
git checkout ProjectC
```

delete all directory not belong to ProjectC

```
git add -A .
git commit -m"All source code of ProjectC"
git push -u origin ProjectC
```

*(But your way isn't best practice.)*

Comment: I can imagine what this answer would look like if OP included more directories in the question

Comment: For easy-to-understand.

Comment: @Leon this isn't a question tagged with bash, and doesn't need to go into that level of detail to communicate the premise of the solution.

Comment: Note that if, say, the changes in the `ProjectA` branch need to be merged back to `master`, it will have to be done with some care and/or manual intervention to avoid deleting more than is wanted in the `master` branch. The `git subtree` command can also help here.

Comment: @BryceDrew This answer could be simplified without using bash scripting - just show the steps of performing the suggested procedure for ProjectA, and add a sentence "repeat above procedure for ProjectB, ProjectC, etc".